# Not able to open local txt file in online python compiler

Tags: python

I have the  problem while openning file in
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ IDE
The code is below

```
f=open("E:\\note/p.txt",'r')
print(f.read())
```

but getting the error
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\note/p.txt'`

Please help me to solve this problem
Thanks

Comment: The code runs on their server, not on your machine. They don't have access to your files.

Answer (score 1):

You have a newline character in your filename. Try this:

```
f = open(r'E:\note\p.txt')
```

By using a raw string, the 'n' is not escaped and therefore the backslash (Windows directory separator) is used literally.

Note that 'r' mode is default and therefore not required

Comment: This also  not work
same error i got

Comment: In that case, that's not where your file is! Are you sure you have a directory called 'note' at the top level of your E: drive? Does that directory contain a file called 'p.txt'?

Comment: @dineshkumar, as mentioned in the comment by Selcuk, you're running the code on a server. It doesn't have the files you intend to open. Have you uploaded/hosted the files anyhow? I suggest you download an IDE or run Python on your PC and not use web apps/online compilers, as it's difficult to manage files/dependencies as you move on and go deeper. I recommend using JetBrains' [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows). It works like a charm if you have good hardware. If you want a lighter code editor, you can always use [VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).

Comment: So, yes, as you've said, the file is local, and to use that file in your Python code, the file needs to be reachable; you can try uploading it if Programiz has such an option. I still suggest you use an IDE or a simple code editor and run Python code locally; on your own PC, as moving the files and using them will be more convenient. Who knows what Programiz does with the code you run!? Running code on your own device is much safer, and you can try programs that need sensitive data without being worried.

Comment: thanks for help but in local code is working but this question asked in interview and they given me programiz compiler there its not working i tried to move p.txt file to desktop but its not working